# redirect product's page to category's page in prestashop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop

have to redirect one specific product's page to one specific category's page, I'm using ps 1.4.7

I try to use .htaccess but It doesn't work,

the code that I used is:

```
RewriteRule ^(300-cat-offline-4)$ http://www.italia-mobili.it/7-sedie [R=301,L]
```

then

```
redirectMatch 301 ^(300-cat-offline-4)$ http://www.italia-mobili.it/7-sedie
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer by myself:

the correct code is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)1012-sedie-pelle-round\.html$ http://www.italia-mobili.it/7-sedie/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

I put this code in the line after

```
RewriteEngine on
```